# Filter rxjs operator on result valuechanges

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I am querying a Firestore (7.5.0) database from Angular (14.2). The *where* clause(s) allow only one range/inequality predicate, so I am trying to use filter to affect the second.  This code

```
let project$: Observable<Project[]> =  this.firestore.collection<Project>('Projects',
      ref => ref.where('EndDt', '>=', startDt)).
      valueChanges().pipe(filter((proj) => {    // Gets whole array once so all or nothing
        console.log('proj: ', proj) ;
        return proj['StartDt'] <= endDt ;
      })) ;
```

Sends filter the entire result (110 documents) all at once, so my true or false return seems like an all or nothing (I could iterate through the array, but again it's all or nothing).  Am I structuring this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RxJs filter operator does not filter the response; it filters the stream. If a value passes the filter function then the stream emits the value. Otherwise, the stream doesn't emit. If you want to filter the results, you need to use the RxJs map operator to transform the emitted value and use the filter on the emitted array.

```
obs$.pipe(map(results => results.filter(val => filterFunction(val))));
```

Comment: Perfect, logging this one.  Tx for the quick and excellent response.